# declaring view models in knockoutjs

Tags: knockout.js

I am new to JavaScript and knockoutjs. This is probably the most basic of questions and I hope not too stupid a one to ask here...

On a lot of the documentation I see the view models being declared in two different ways. Sometimes they are declared as functions and at other times they are plain objects. What is the difference and what are the scenarios in which I would use each.

```
   var viewModel = { 
       property: ko.observable() 
   }
```

Or

```
   var viewModel = function(){
       this.property = ko.observable() 
   }
```

Apologies if this is a dumb question....

Comment: you can't use `property: ko.observable()` inside the function, but rather `this.property = ko.observable();`

Comment: thanks xec, my bad. I have amended the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second example is a constructor function in JavaScript - since JavaScript doesn't have "classes", that's how you implement "classlike" instance-creation.

More info: http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/oopjs2.shtml

Comment: Thanks Val, appreciate the link. I have lots of reading to do ;)

Comment: object literals (your first example) are very simple to use and that's why many examples use them. however using functions (and patterns like the module pattern and revealing module pattern) to create view models are a bit more robust. while learning Knockout, dont worry too much about which you use. but certainly read up on those topics and it will make more sense as you get deeper into KO.